# Parse file text to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, text, nested

I have text file with contains :

```
0,ke-2,0.0986089045676918
0,putar,0.141656526869241
1,film,0.110677581313152
1,aveng,0.12035192077391
```

i want to parse the file txt to dictionary with structure like this :

[image: structure]

```
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> openNormalization()
    {
        var temp = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>>();
        var file = File.ReadLines("normalization.txt").Cast<string>();
        foreach (string f in file)
        {
            var doc = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            string fwd = "0";
            string[] entry = f.Split(',');
            if (entry[0] == fwd)
            {
                doc.Add(entry[1], Convert.ToDouble(entry[2]));
                fwd = entry[0];
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Add(int.Parse(fwd), doc);
                doc = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                doc.Add(entry[1], Convert.ToDouble(entry[2]));
                fwd = entry[0];
            }
        return temp;
    }
```

[image: how ca i fix it?]

how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `entry[2]` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: entry[2] is 0.0986089045676918 i want to convert to double because i must to add to dictionary<string,double>

Comment: Is your code running in a culture which, by default, uses `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator?

Comment: What happens if you use `double d = double.Parse(entry[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`? Does that work?

Comment: my code running on . for double value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code might work but it only works in the situation where there's **only 2 keys (0 & 1)**, if you add key `2`, everything will break

You can use `LINQ` with `GroupBy`

See my code below

```
private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> openNormalization()
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines("normalization.txt");

    return lines
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .GroupBy(item => Convert.ToInt32(item[0]))
        .ToDictionary(groupValues => groupValues.Key, groupValues => groupValues.ToDictionary(item => item[1], item => Convert.ToDouble(item[2])));
}
```

Comment: but i have 0 to 80 for keys

Comment: Exactly, you would need 80 if clauses for 80 keys